# How to go back to the old console?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I've been using the old console for quite some time.

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/

I tried the new console, by clicking in the banner link, "New Bluemix". But would like to go back the old console again. I've tried `?direct=classic` but that doesn't work. The old console is still around, but I know that eventually I won't be able to go back to the old version. I just would like to use it for now.

**How do I go back to the old console?**

Comment: I clearned all `*.bluemix.net` cookies, and that seems to work, but it also logs me out too. Not sure which specific cookie I can delete that would suffice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some digging the the exact cookie you can delete is called `bm_newexperience` which has the value `new`. If you delete that one cookie then you can go back to the old classic experience at https://console.ng.bluemix.net/

Comment: There it is. I don't know why I didn't see it before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Going incognito works for me. Not sure it's the correct route though.

Answer (score 0):

I checked with the Bluemix console team and verified that the only way to revert back to the "old console" is to delete all your browser cookies.